# Single callback macro for multiple form controls (ListBoxes to be specific)

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to store selected values from a listbox (Excel 2010) with multi selection enabled. This is easily done by iterating through the items in the list to see if they are selected. However, upon adding a number of listboxes, i have to create a callback for each:

```
Sub ListBox1_Changed()
Call DoStuff(Worksheets("Sheet1").ListBoxes(1))
End Sub

Sub ListBox2_Changed()
Call DoStuff(Worksheets("Sheet1").ListBoxes(2))
End Sub

Sub DoStuff(L as ListBox)
'Do stuff here
Sub
```

Eventually I will end up with a large number of these ListBoxes across multiple worksheets.

Now my question is: Is it possible to reference the specific box that called the macro and assigning this single function for all my listboxes? I'm guessing something like:

```
Sub ListBox_Changed(ByVal L as Object)
' This will not work btw ^^^^^^^^

' Magic code goes here.
Call DoStuff(L_converted_to_ListBox_Format)
End Sub
```

Please note, that I'm not using userforms but have just put the listbox directly in the worksheet.

Thanks!

Comment: Siddharth has a good write-up on this here http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/vba-control-arrays/

Comment: updated link: http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Application.Caller` to determine which `ListBox` called the `Sub`, like this

```
Sub ListBox_Changed()
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim lb As ListBox
    v = Application.Caller
    On Error Resume Next
    Set lb = Me.ListBoxes(v)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo 0
    DoStuff lb
End Sub

Sub DoStuff(lb As ListBox)
    Debug.Print lb.List(lb.Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error when using the "Me" keyword, but using ActiveSheet instead works perfectly well, i.e.
`Set lb = ActiveSheet.ListBoxes(v)`

Comment: `Me` applies if the code is placed in the `Worksheet` module.  If it's placed in a standard Moldule then `ActiveSheet` will work _provided_ the sheet the ListBox is on is actually active

Comment: I suppose it's a fair assumption that the user has the sheet active when changing the listbox within the sheet (as I mentioned the listbox is within the sheet and not in a user form). Once again, Thanks!

Comment: Yeh, if it is the user that changes the list.  What if its changed by code? I think it just leaves an unnecessary hole.